# Can I force embedding code to not be clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, embed

is there a way to prevent the user from clicking on this counter and abandoning the page where it has been embedded? Also, if there is a solution please be aware I'm not a programmer.  Thank you.

```
<div data-type="countdown" data-id="266361" class="tickcounter" style="width: 500px; height: 125px; margin: 0 auto">
   <a href="//www.tickcounter.com/countdown/266361/este-programa-cierra-registros-en" title="Este programa cierra registros en">
    Este programa cierra registros en
  </a>
  <a href="//www.tickcounter.com/" title="Countdown">
    Countdown
  </a>
</div>
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) { 
      var js, pjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return; 
      js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//www.tickcounter.com/static/js/loader.js"; 
      pjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, pjs); 
  }(document, "script", "tickcounter-sdk"));
</script>
```

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("tickcounter")[0].addEventListener("click",e => (e.preventDefault(),e.stopPropagation())); may work

Comment: Hi Jonas, thank you. I  just tried it but the timer disappears altogether from the page, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with CSS via `pointer-events: none`, I believe!

I've put an example of this here: https://jsfiddle.net/26vmkxLo/

Let me know if this works for you! Thanks.

Comment: Perfect solution, Thank you very much Henry!!

Comment: Happy to help @Ulises! Let me know if you have any other issues.